# Have html element follow finger on jQuery mobile swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, multi-touch, gesture

I have a div on which I listen for swipe events using jQuery mobile.

I was wondering **how I could get the div to follow and move with the finger from the time that the swipe starts until the time that the swipe ends**?

Almost like draggable only while the swipe is happening.

Although I would prefer to not use jQuery UI.

How can I do this properly and in the best way possible?

My method of doing this was on mouse down, set the offset of the div to the x location of the mouse. But that fires every pixel and seem inefficient. Also it happens on mouse-down, not on swipe.

Here is my code that listens for the swipe, in this case swipe right:

```
$('#main').on('swiperight', '.dataCard', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // what happens on swipe here
});
```

Now, how can I get `.dataCard` to follow the finger as it swipes until the finger is picked up?

Comment: I would imagine the .dataCard elemnt would need some sort of absolute positioning in the container.  Does the "event" object have an x, y coordinate?  if so then change the top and left of the .dataCard element to be those x/y values.

Comment: @revlayle No, it is `position:relative;`. How do I get the event's x / y coordinates? How do I check if the event has coordinates? And where do I put this-- inside, where `// what happens on swipe here` is?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can inspect the event in a breaking in a debugger.  Also, you cannot change positions of a "relative" element, it will always be in document flow position (hence why I asked if you had made the element absolute).